# How to make paging at js and set the limit content for go to next page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How to make **paging at js** and **set the limit** content for go to next page automatic, here my code

```
initialProcess() {
    this.processResult();
}

processResult(){

    let result = window.helper.importJSON('http://api.aipj.ordent.co/api/galleries?orderBy=<created_at&limit=9&page=');
    let self = this;
    result.then(function(e){
        e.data.forEach(function(item){
            // item.image_cover = JSON.parse(item.image_cover);
        });

        if(!self.multiple){
            console.log(e.data);
            self.set('content',e.data);               
            let gallery = window.helper.importJSON('http://api.aipj.ordent.co/api/galleries/' + ((self.slug)));
            gallery.then(function(value){
                if(value.data.file){
                    self.set('multipleImages',true);
                }else{
                    self.set('multipleImages',false);
                }
            self.set('activeGallery', value.data);
            console.log(value.data);
            self.$.StartContent.scrollIntoView({'behaviour': 'smooth'});
            })
        }else{
            console.log(e.data);
            self.set('content',e.data);                
        }
    });
}
```

i tried before but just limit the content active without automatically go the next page for other content. Thank you

Comment: Please post the code, not a screenshot of it.